# Will the bitcoin value keep rising at steady rate, if bitcoin mining is stopped right now

Tags: value, money-supply

If no new coins are created by mining after 12 million bitcoins as of today, what kind of impact will it have on bitcoin value. Transaction fees will still be set for confirmations.

Comment: If everybody stopped mining right now, bitcoin would be dead. The mining process is what confirms bitcoin transactions, without it, no transactions can ever be made and validated.

Comment: edit: if transaction fees becomes reward and new coin rewards were stopped

Comment: In that case, you might want to look at these questions: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3111 , http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/876 They deal with exactly this problem.